# How to send data to PayPal from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, controller

Usually if I want to make a payment via PayPal through a Rails app, I prepare a payment form in a view and after clicking that is a user redirected to PayPal, where (s)he pay and is redirected back to the app.

I would need send a regular form with data to controller, then to save them there and then according to what's in the sent data to redirect user to PayPal, where (s)he would pay.

But how to do something like this? Is even this approach allowed to make a payment with using PayPal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to consume the PayPal API. This may provide a better experience for your user since you won't have to bounce them out to PayPal and back.

It looks like there's a gem that may help you out: [paypal_adaptive](https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive)

I haven't tried it, so your mileage may vary.